# How can i fix this parse error

Tags: php, wordpress

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW
i am a beginner at best when it comes to php

below is the code

```
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
          <?php $mytrails = new WP_Querry)
               'post_type' => '$mytrails'
          )); ?>
          <?php while($mytrails->have_posts()) : $mytrails->the_post();?>
              <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="panel">
                <div class="thumbtitle group">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');?>
```

Comment: You could check some examples on http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query after reverting your code to what it was before.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<?php $mytrails = new WP_Querry)
  'post_type' => '$mytrails'
)); ?>
```

With:

```
<?php $mytrails = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => $mytrails
) ); ?>
```

In your version there's a typo in WP_Query, a missing array, a closing bracket where there shouldn't be one, and a variable inside single quotes.